# How to disable XMLUnit DTD validation?

Tags: java, xml, testing, xmlunit-2

I am trying to compare two XHTML documents using [XMLUnit](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit) 2.2.0. However, it is taking too long. I guess the library is downloading DTD files from Internet.

How can I disable DTD validation? I am using the following test code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Diff d = DiffBuilder.compare(
                Input.fromString(
                     "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \n"
                    +"     \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n"
                    +"<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n"
                    +"     <head></head>\n"
                    +"     <body>some content 1</body>\n"
                    +"</html>")).withTest(
                Input.fromString(                   
                     "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \n"
                    +"     \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n"
                    +"<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n"
                    +"     <head></head>\n"
                    +"     <body>some content 2</body>\n"
                    +"</html>")).ignoreWhitespace().build();
        if(d.hasDifferences()) 
            for (Difference dd: d.getDifferences()) {
                System.out.println(dd.toString());
            }
    }
}
```

Reading the [XMLUnit Javadoc](http://www.xmlunit.org/api/java/master/org/xmlunit/builder/DiffBuilder.html#withDocumentBuilderFactory-javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory-) of `DiffBuilder.withDocumentBuilderFactory()`, I thought I could do this setting a document builder factory like this...

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

dbf.setValidating(false);
dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

Diff d = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(...)).withTest(
     Input.fromString(...)).withDocumentBuilderFactory(dbf)
          .ignoreWhitespace().build();
```

It did not work. My code runs fast just when I remove the DOCTYPE definition from the XHTML snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withDocumentBuilderFactory` is exactly what you want to use but unfortunately `ignoreWhitespace` defeats it.

Under the covers `DiffBuilder` creates a `WhitespaceStrippedSource` which creates a DOM `Document` without using the `DocumentBuilderFactory` you've configured. This is a bug. Do you want to create an issue for this?

A workaround using XMLUnit 2.2.0 is to create the `Document`s yourself, something like

```
Document control = Convert.toDocument(Input.fromString(...).build(), dbf);
Document test = ...
Diff d = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromDocument(control))
             .withTest(Input.fromDocument(test))
             .ignoreWhitespace().build();
```

*Edit:* The bug has been fixed in XMLUnit 2.2.1 and the code of the question should now work without any changes.

Comment: Your workaround works, but it seems there is not a `Convert.toDocument` overload that accepts `DiffBuilder` objects returned by `Input.fromString`. So, I used a `StreamSource` instead:

`Convert.toDocument(new StreamSource(new StringReader(...`

Would you like to edit your answer?

Comment: Yes, I am going to open an issue for this at https://github.com/xmlunit

Comment: Thanks, I've added `.build()` to turn the `Builder` into the `Source`.